# Problem with dialog box using Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, flot

dial and place are the two divisions which exist in the html code that calls the function. 
I am able to open up both of them but not able to embed the graph using plot in the 'place' division after it is opening up via the 'Draw' button.
It works fine only when I open both the boxes initially.

```
function abcd (dial,place,xrange){

var dial = conv(dial)

var xr = document.getElementById("xrange");

var yr = document.getElementById("yrange");

var gtype = document.getElementById("pattern");

xr.value = ""; yr.value = ""; gtype.value = "Line" ;

var place = conv(place);

$(dial).dialog("close");

$(dial).dialog("open");

$(place).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: 'Explode',
            height: 500,
            width: 450,
            modal: true})

$(dial).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: 'Explode',
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: false,
            buttons :
                        { "Draw" : function() {
                        $((place)).dialog("open");


            $(function () {

//manipulate input values to plot data

    $.plot(document.getElementById(plac2), [ {data:d1roe,label:"abc"},
                                 {data:d1roa, label:"xyz"} ], {
                  series: {stack: 0},
                  xaxis: {ticks: ticks},
                  ticks: ticks
               });


});

//function open(xyz) {$(xyz).dialog("open");}

function conv (myid) { 
return ( '#' + myid );
 }
```

Comment: Can you format your code !! Seems missing some ;

Comment: Is that the only place where you init jquery `dialog` on place and dial elements? because you can try to close or open, but it will do it with default parameters the first time... after that, they will open with the options you chose

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a quick fix for it.
The problem was that the dialog will open but will not be manipulated by flot because it was unable to extract the width and height of the dialog box. So before opening the dialog we can fix the height and width.

Specifying height in the style sheet of html did not work in my case.

```
 $(dial).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: 'Explode',
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: false,
        buttons :
                    { "Draw" : function() {
                     $(place).width(500);    // can take this as an input as well
                     $(place).height(500);
                     $(place).dialog("open");
                     //ploting code
}})}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing you need for flot to work is for your plac2 div to have a width and height, and be visible (i.e. drawn to the screen).  So before you plot, try alerting whether your div has width and height:

```
var placeholder = document.getElementById(plac2);
alert($(placeholder).width()+','+$(placeholder).height());

//plotting code here
```

Let us know what happens.

Comment: It shows 0,0 . But I initialised when I defined the division and in the above code as well.$(place).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: 'Explode',
            height: 500,
            width: 450,})
by the way plac2 is place only

Comment: Make sure that plac2 has CSS visibility:visible, and display:block before you plot, that might help.

Comment: I did that as well. Nothing changed. I was able to get a dialog when I manually set the height and width of it though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rohan, write up an answer to your own question, and I'd give you a vote!